# Prove/ disprove equivalence relation and prove cardinality of subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

$M$ is a non-empty set and $R \subseteq M \times M$ is a relation on $M$. A R-Clique is a set $C \subseteq M$, with for every $x$ and $y$ in $C$: $xRy$.

a)Prove or disprove: If $|M| > 1$ and R is reflexive and symmetrical, then there exists an R-Clique $C$ with at least two elements($|C| \geq2$).

b)Now let there be two R-Cliques $C_1,C_2$ with $M = C_1 \cup C_2$ and $C_1 \cap C_2 = \emptyset$. Prove or disprove: R is an equivalence relation (reflexive, symmetrical and transitive).

---

a) (i)$|M| > 1$

(ii)$\forall x,y \in M: xRx$ and $xRy \rightarrow yRx$

To prove: $i$ and $ii \rightarrow |C| \geq 2$

Since  $C \subseteq M$, $C$ can also be entire $M$, which means $C=M$. Since $|M| > 1 \rightarrow |C| > 1 \rightarrow |C| \geq 2$.

b)I have to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $C_1$ and on $C_2$. Then it will also be an equivalence relation on M.
But how do I show that since it's not specified what $R$ actually does.

Answer (score 0):

For (a), you say

> Since C⊆M, C can also be entire M, which means C=M.

It's true that that is a possibility, but it's hardly a necessity that $C=M$.  (In fact, the claim they ask you to prove is not true.  See if you can think of a symmetric and reflexive relation on $M$ where all of its cliques are of size 1.

---

For (b), they are defining $xRy$ as it either being the case that $x\in C_1$ and $y\in C_1$ or that $x\in C_2$ and $y\in C_2$.  This is enough of a definition for you to determine that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: So in a) would the $=$ relation suffice. If $x=y$ it would mean that there is only one letter in $C$.